# Почему GSON больше не работает как нужно?

Tags: java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
a2 = gson.fromJson("[5, 374, 7]", int[].class)
System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(a));
```

Выдает пустоту! Gson свеже-скачанный, на новом нетбуке.

Comment: `Arrays.toString(a2)` может?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка же в коде - результат кладете в a2, а выводите a.

Comment: Тогда уж это вообще не должно компилироваться

Comment: @BigTows Автор не показал как переменные обьявлены, потому как и `a2 = gson.fromJson("[5, 374, 7]", int[].class)` не должно компилироваться тоже.